# Why it is hard to use vue-i18n in vue data() (why it is not reactive)

Tags: vue.js, vue-i18n

I am using *vue-i18n* in a vue project. And I found it really ***confusing*** when using some data in vue `data` with i18n. Then if I change `locale`, that data is not **reactive**. I tried to return that `data` from another `computed data` but anyways it is not **reactive** because i18n is written in `data`. ***My situation - *** I want to show *table* with **dropdown**(list of columns with checkbox) above it. When user ***checks*** a column it will be showed in table if ***unchecks*** it won't. It is working **fine** until I change `locale`. After changing `locale` `table columns` is not **translated** but `dropdown items` is reactively translated and my code won't work anymore.  Here is some code to explain better: In my `myTable.vue` component I use **bootstrap-vue table** - 
 `template` in *myTable.vue*

```
<vs-dropdown vs-custom-content vs-trigger-click>
  <b-link href.prevent class="card-header-action btn-setting" style="font-size: 1.4em">
    <i class="fa fa-th"></i>
  </b-link>
  <vs-dropdown-menu class="columns-dropdown">
    <visible-columns :default-fields="columns" @result="columnListener"></visible-columns>
  </vs-dropdown-menu>
</vs-dropdown>

<b-table class="generalTableClass table-responsive" :fields="computedFieldsForTable">custom content goes here</b-table>
```

`script` in *myTable.vue*

```
data(){
  return {
   fieldsForTable: [];
  }
},

computed: {
  computedFieldsForTable () {
    return this.fieldsForTable;
  },

  columns() {
    return [
     {
       key: 'id',
       label: this.$t('id'),,
       visible: true,
       changeable: true
     },
     {
       key: 'fullName',
       label: this.$t('full-name'),,
       visible: true,
       changeable: true
     },
     {
       key: 'email',
       label: this.$t('email'),,
       visible: true,
       changeable: true
     }
    ]
  }
},

mounted () {
  this.fieldsForTable = this.filterColumns(this.columns);
},

methods: {
  filterColumns(columns = []) {
    return columns.filter(column => {
      if (column.visible) {
        return column
      }
    })
  },
  columnListener ($event) {
    this.fieldsForTable = this.filterColumns($event)
  }
}
```

Can someone give me some advice for this situation ?

*EDIT AFTER SOME DEBUGGING: I think when filtering `columns`(in `computed`) and returning it for `fieldsForTable` inside `filterColumns(columns)` method, it actually returning array(of objects) with `label='Label Name'` not `label=this.$t('labelName')`. So after filtering the new array has nothing to do with **vue-i18n**. My last chance is **reloading the page** when locale changes.

Comment: Sorry. I'm confusing that which part do you use `vue-i18n`. I don't see any `$t` or `locale` changed in your code.

Comment: @bcjohn sorry, I edited the question. I am using it in `computed()` -> `columns`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Trying modify `computedFieldsForTable` as follows. You need to reference `this.columns` in `computedFieldsForTable`, so that Vue can detect the change of labels in `this.columns`.

```
computedFieldsForTable () {
   return this.filterColumns(this.columns);
},
```

EDITED: put your `this.columns` in data. Then

```
columnListener ($event) {
  this.columns = $event;
}
```

I hope i didn't misunderstand what you mean.

### EDITED (again):

Maybe this is the last chance that I think it can work. Put `columns` in `computed()` still and remove `computedFieldsForTable`. Finally, just leave `fieldsForTable` and bind it on `fields` of `<b-table>`.

```
watch: {
  columns(val) {
    this.fieldsForTable = this.filterColumns(val)
  }
},
method: {
  columnListener ($event) {
    this.fieldsForTable = this.filterColumns($event)
  }
}
```

However, I think it is better and easier to reload page whenever **local change**. Especially when your `columns` have a more complex data structure.

Comment: I tried your suggestion, translation worked fine. But in this case how to write my `columnListener($event)` method, because I need it to **show and hide**  *table columns*. It is called from `vs-dropdown-menu` -> `visible-columns` (when user checks or unchecks the **column name**) and it receives *changed* array of column names

Comment: Thank you for your answers @bcjohn. I tried your *edited answer* but now when `locale` changes **table headers** and **dropdown items** is not translated *reactively*. I think the reason is putting `columns` in `data()`

Comment: Thank you @bcjohn, You are the man. **That watcher** helped me to fix that translation issue. I tried to put `watcher` to `locale` didn't help, why I haven't thought about the `columns` earlier. I think your answer best suits this kind of tricky situation. Accepted it.